# Unable to populate ListView with rawQuery command in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

I'm having some problems populating a `ListView` in Android with a `rawQuery` command, I'm hoping some new eyes on it helps out.

I'm using a method to copy my own database over from the assets folder, which I believe is working correctly.  The database is being copied over correctly, as I'm watching this happen in `DDMS`.  I'm also getting `log.i` entries that are telling me the database is being opened properly as well.  I'm not getting any errors when I Logcat, but nothing is populating my `ListView`.

Is there something wrong with my command below to query the DB and report back?

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
        private void fillData() {
        Cursor c =  myDbHelper.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master",   null);
            startManagingCursor(c);
        // Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list.
            String[] from = new String[]{"name"};

            // an array of the views that we want to bind those fields too.
            int[] to = new int[]{R.id.listview};

            // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
            SimpleCursorAdapter notes = 
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_view, c, from, to);
            setListAdapter(notes);             
      }
```

Here is my lists.xml file where I want the results of the ListView to populate:

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

      <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
         <TextView
            android:text = "Lists"
            style="@style/HeaderText"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:gravity="center" />
          <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient"
            android:layout_height="1dp" />
        <LinearLayout 
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/searchText"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/searchButton"
                android:text="Search"
                android:background = "@drawable/main_buttons"
                style="@style/ButtonText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />"

   </LinearLayout>
        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />  

             <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:background="#000000"
               android:text="No data"
               style="@style/ButtonText"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
```

And finally, the `list_view` layout is just a `TextView` to populate the correct list from the `rawQuery` command.

Comment: is you `TextView` in the `list_view` called `listview` ?

Comment: Yes, it is.  I just didn't copy it in here.

Comment: @ADK Are you sure you call this method, `fillData()`? `SimpleCursorAdapter` requires that the cursor on which is based to have the `_id`(`INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`) field as part of it(that you don't have in you query), this should throw an `Exception`. Also what do you want to do with that `rawQuery`, get the names of the table of your `SQLite` database?

Comment: Can you elaborate on calling the fillData() method? I don't think I am at all (pardon my newbish).  In this case, I am simply trying to print a list of table names out, yes.

Comment: @ADK You have to call somewhere in the code the method `fillData()` to set the adapter, like in the notepad tutorial (Step 8) http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex1.html (see the call to `fillData()` in the `onCreate` method).

Comment: Wow, I think I was missing that part.  Thank you so much for catching that.  I'm now getting an error related to the _id field.  However I specifically did create that field in the database.  Do I need to do something special with that when using rawQuery?

Comment: @ADK Did you solve the `_id` Exception? If not tell my so i can give you a solution. Also your `rawQuery` should be `SELECT name FROM sqlite_master
WHERE type='table'` if you want only the tables, i think `SQLite` is also storing other things in that table(indexes) so it's better to filter the `select` query.

Comment: I solved the _id problem by using something like "SELECT _id as _id, Name FROM Content".  this is correctly returning the fields in my Name field in the Content Table.  I am still unable to get it to work using the "SELECT name FROM sqlite_Master WHERE type = 'table' command...it says _id does not exist.

Comment: @ADK Have you tested my answer below?

Comment: I will do it when I get home from work...I forgot to load the TeamViewer this morning. :)

Comment: No go..it returns a NULL pointer.  I think what I will do is just load the table names into their own table and use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display the tables names in your list you could try this `fillData()` method:

```
private void fillData() {
        Cursor c = myDbHelper.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master", null);
        ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            values.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")));
        }
        c.close();
        // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
        ArrayAdapter<String> notes = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.list_view, values);
        setListAdapter(notes);
    }
```

`ListView` requires that the cursor on which is based to have an `_id` column. But in that table you don't have an `_id` to add to the query so you could try to parse the cursor from the raw query into an `ArrayList` and then bind it to a simple `ArrayAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok there s something weird here. [The reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) says

> ListActivity has a default layout that consists of a single,
>   full-screen list in the center of the screen. However, if you desire,
>   you can customize the screen layout by setting your own view layout
>   with setContentView() in onCreate(). To do this, your own view MUST
>   contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list" (or list if
>   it's in code)

So, it says we should be using `@android:id/list`, like you do.

I suppose you are following the Notebook tutorial. Cos, I have a similar case where I have my own layout (`entries_list.xml`) for my `ListActivity` smth like

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
... some other elements here
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textFilterEnabled="true" >
    </ListView>
... some other elements here

</LinearLayout>
```

So I use my own naming: `@+id/android:list` instead. Then I am explicitly setting the content view of my `ListActivity` with `setContentView(R.layout.entries_list);`. This works for me. You can maybe give it a try.

Hope it helps.